# removing square brackets and apostrophes around a list

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that takes a list of names and sorts it alphabetically then repeats it back.

Here is my code:

```
question = input('Students: ')
roll = print('Class Roll')
students = question.split()
students.sort()
v1 = 0
v2 = 1
for i in range(len(students)):
  person = students[v1:v2]
  print(person)
  v1 = v1 + 1
  v2 = v2 + 1
```

When I run the code and type in a list of names it repeats it back with [' '] around each name.
Like this:

```
Students: Bob Adam Carl Fred
Class Roll
['Adam']
['Bob']
['Carl']
['Fred']
```

The only thing that I can't figure out how to fix is removing the [' '] around each name. When I try to use [2:-2] to remove them it just outputs [] for the number of names I typed in. Is there a way to remove them and if so how? I've tried to find an answer to this but I couldn't see one anywhere.

Comment: Use `students[i]` instead of slicing the list, and get rid of `v1` and `v2`.  Or better yet, just do `for person in students:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are printing a slice of the list, not the string at each index. This gives you a list of one item, then prints that one-item list, hence the brackets and apostrophes (that is python's representation of a list):

```
person = students[v1:v2]
```

Eg:

```
>>> listy = ['a', 'b', 'c']
# if I take a slice that's just the middle item, I would get
>>> print(listy[1:2])
['b']
>>> print(listy[0:1])
['a']
# compare with
>>> print(listy[1])
b    
>>> print(listy[0])
a
```

You are also making it wayyyyy harder on yourself that it needs to be. You probably want:

```
for person in students:
  # person = students[v1:v2]
  print(person)
  # v1 = v1 + 1
  # v2 = v2 + 1
```

Comment: Wow thank you, I'm kinda new to this so I'm not very good. Yet.

Comment: No worries, we all started somewhere. This is a hobby for me, and trust me, I have asked my share of stupid questions on SO and gotten my share of downvotes. SO is a great resource, but not always the most tolerant of new people. Your question was well-written.

The other thing you should be aware of is that people will give you one answer, then continue to edit (update) it, so don't assume that answers won't evolve somewhat.